# Template function for increasing and decreasing priority queue

Tags: c++, templates, priority-queue

I wanted to write a template function for printing increasing and decreasing priority queues. Currently I have implemented it as

```
void print_queue1(priority_queue<int> q, string s){
    cout << "Value of prior queue " << s << " is : [";

    while(!q.empty()){
        cout << " " << q.top() << ",";
        q.pop();
    }
    cout << "]" << endl;
}


// min-heap
void print_queue2(priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int>> q, string s){
    cout << "Value of prior queue " << s << " is : [";

    while(!q.empty()){
        cout << " " << q.top() << ",";
        q.pop();
    }
    cout << "]" << endl;
}
```

Is there some way to write a single template function that can do this?

Comment: Have you seen [the three template arguments that `priority_queue` uses](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue)?  Your function could have those same parameters, used in the same way.

Comment: that uses `<T, std::vector<T>, std::less<T>>`, i dont think this can work for std::greater<T>

Comment: Those are just the default types.  I'm saying `template<class T,class Container, class Compare>` would work.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I wasn't aware `class Compare` can be used like that

Comment: Can you write it in an answer, might be helpful for someone begginer in future

Comment: You're thinking of others here... I like that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [variadic function template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) for this.  Since the logic is the same regardless of the queue type, we can just accept any type of queue like

```
template <typename... Params>
void print_queue(priority_queue<Params...> q, string s){
    cout << "Value of prior queue " << s << " is : [";

    while(!q.empty()){
        cout << " " << q.top() << ",";
        q.pop();
    }
    cout << "]" << endl;
}
```

Here, `Params` will be deduced from the template parameters of the supplied `priority_queue` for you by the compiler and it will stamp out a concrete function for each different parameter set.

Comment: Oh, this looks pretty good. Wasn't aware of this. Thanks

Comment: @Naman No worries.  Glad to help.  Variadic templates allows you to do a lot of neat things like this.

Answer (score 2):

The template class `std::priority_queue` uses [three template type parameters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue).

```
template<
    class T,
    class Container = std::vector<T>,
    class Compare = std::less<typename Container::value_type>
> class priority_queue;
```

You may use those same three parameters in your function to accept any instantiation of `std::priority_queue`.

```
template<class T, class Container, class Compare>
void print_queue(priority_queue<T,Container,Compare> q, string s){
    cout << "Value of prior queue " << s << " is : [";

    while(!q.empty()){
        cout << " " << q.top() << ",";
        q.pop();
    }
    cout << "]" << endl;
}
```

Or, you may remove/restrict any one of them to enforce a subset of priority queues..

```
template<class Container, class Compare>
void print_queue(priority_queue<int,Container,Compare> q, string s){
    // This function is really only designed for priority queues of int!
    cout << "Value of prior queue " << s << " is : [";

    while(!q.empty()){
        cout << " " << q.top() << ",";
        q.pop();
    }
    cout << "]" << endl;
}
```